# Comparing month to index in Jekyll for loop not working

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to create progress bar using Jekyll with following code but this does not seem to work. Can anyone point me to right direction please?

```
{% assign m = site.time | date: '%-m' %}
{% for i in (1..12) %}
  {% if i == m %}
    <li>Current month is {{ i }}.</li>
  {% elsif i <= m %}
    <li>{{ i }} month is passed.</li>
  {% elsif i >= m %}
    <li>{{ i }} is an upcoming month.</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the first line:

```
{% assign m = site.time | date: '%-m' %}
```

After this operation `m` will be a string, which then you compare to number which basically fails:

```
Liquid Exception: comparison of Fixnum with String failed in
```

To convert string to number [use](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-can-i-convert-a-number-to-a-string-185373) `| plus: 0 %`, so your assignment will look like this:

```
{% assign m = site.time | date: '%-m' | plus: 0 %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.